# Full Calendar, TimeGridDay view plugin issue while using with angular and loaded for the first time

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

[Error Image of Time on the left side being exceed the vertical line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxen6.png)

While Using TimeGrid View as a plugin in full calendar, while loading the calendar for the first time, how to increase the width of the time view(How to increase the Y-axis)
I am using angular 8 and the versions are all up to date, I used  .fc.fc-axis {width: 42.25px !important}, and tried to increase the width, also used slotWidth Property from full calendar but it did not help!

Comment: The most likely reason for this kind of visual problem is that you tried to customise the CSS of fullCalendar (either directly, or by overloading rules in your own CSS) and made a mistake, or that there is some other CSS in your page which accidentally interferes with fullCalendar's elements. Try removing other CSS from your page, leaving just the fullCalendar default CSS, and see if you still have the issue. Also your browser's element inspector tool can tell you what rules are being applied to an element and where they come from.

Comment: Either way, without any code or a reproducible example, there's nothing much anyone can do to help you. This isn't an issue in fullCalendar with the code and CSS it provides, so we can assume the problem is in your code, which we cannot see.

Comment: Yes, i inspected there and it says, we have to use .fc.fc-axis class and modify the width, as i mentioned, I did that change in scss and found no help. is there any property from full calendar to change the width? or where I can find full calendar css file(default one) as I am not changing the default behavior of CSS. here is the code,

Comment: Where is the code? You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61857502/edit) button of your question to update it.

Comment: No there is no specific property of fullCalendar to change the width. As I explained, the width would normally be set correctly in fullCalendar so that the text fits inside it - check any demo to see that. So if it's not working for you, probably there's some conflict with other CSS. I suggested using element inspector to find the conflict (because it tells you what rules are applied to the element and where they come from - maybe something overrides the width that fullCalendar had set?). I didn't mean you should use it to try and make even more changes.

Comment: Thanks! changed in global.scss and Finally worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked,

Full Calendar does have the root class .fc-axis. So, as I was facing issue while opening the the page for the first time(.ie ngOnInit), so a code in global.scss worked like magic!

.fc-axis { width: 100px !important;}
Now, as per the requirement we can change the inline elements too.